# Can embeded browser (chrome) use GCM for Push Notification

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging

I have embeded browser in my windows application using CEF.Can this browser which is rendered in my application window, use GCM(google cloud messaging) for receiving Push notification.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the documentation about [Web Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/). Push is based on service workers because service workers operate in the background. This means the only time code is run for a push notification (in other words, the only time the battery is used) is when the user interacts with a notification by clicking it or closing it. If you're not familiar with them, check out the [service worker introduction](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers).

With a service worker registration you call showNotification on a registration object.

```
serviceWorkerRegistration.showNotification(title, options);
```

The `title` argument appears as a heading in the notification. The `options` argument is an object literal that sets the other properties of a notification. A typical options object looks something like this:

```
{
  "body": "Did you make a $1,000,000 purchase at Dr. Evil...",
  "icon": "images/ccard.png",
  "vibrate": [200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 400],
  "tag": "request",
  "actions": [
    { "action": "yes", "title": "Yes", "icon": "images/yes.png" },
    { "action": "no", "title": "No", "icon": "images/no.png" }
  ]
}
```

Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web) for additional information.